# required ListView's item is not selected

Tags: android

This piece of code `overrides` `onNewIntent()` method of an Activity. In this method I set *selected* an item of `ListView` as a result of clicking notification. The problem is that; when there are two notiications then on clicking first notification required item is highlighted but on clicking second notiication previous item highlighted again. So please help.

**Code:**

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent new_notification) {

        caller = new_notification.getExtras().getString("CALLER");
        if(caller.equals("GenNot")) {
            int myScrollTo = new_notification.getExtras().getInt("ID");
            Log.e("SEE NOW", "myScrollTo # "+myScrollTo, new Exception());
            remindersList.requestFocusFromTouch();
            remindersList.setSelection(myScrollTo);
        }
    }
```

**Notiication Code:**

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;



public class GenerateNotification {

    public static void reminderNotification(Context context, int notification_id, String document_id, String name, String date, Location location) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewReminders.class);
        intent.putExtra("CALLER","GenNot");
        intent.putExtra("ID", notification_id);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notification_id, intent, 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        mBuilder.setTicker("Smart Locator");
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(name);
        DetailsContainer dc = new LocationDetails(context).getDetails(location);
        mBuilder.setContentText(date + ", " + dc.area + " " + dc.locality);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(document_id, notification_id, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem in my project. It was solved by calling [`pendingIntent.cancel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#cancel()) after receiving.

I saved a link to `PendingIntent` before posting a notification in a `Map` and then found it using `notification_id`

```
private final HashMap<String, PendingIntent> mIntents = new HashMap<String, PendingIntent>(); 
...
// on post
mIntents.put(challenge.getId(), pendingIntent);
...
// on click
if (mIntents.containsKey(challengeId)) {
    mIntents.remove(challengeId).cancel();
}
```

Also there is a good explanation in [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html):

> A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by
>   the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This
>   means that, even if its owning application's process is killed, the
>   PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have
>   been given it. If the creating application later re-retrieves the same
>   kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data,
>   categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a
>   PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid, and
>   can thus call cancel() to remove it.
>
> Because of this behavior, it is important to know when two Intents are
>   considered to be the same for purposes of retrieving a PendingIntent.
>   A common mistake people make is to create multiple PendingIntent
>   objects with Intents that only vary in their "extra" contents,
>   expecting to get a different PendingIntent each time. This does not
>   happen. The parts of the Intent that are used for matching are the
>   same ones defined by Intent.filterEquals. If you use two Intent
>   objects that are equivalent as per Intent.filterEquals, then you will
>   get the same PendingIntent for both of them.
>
> There are two typical ways to deal with this.
>
> If you truly need multiple distinct PendingIntent objects active at
>   the same time (such as to use as two notifications that are both shown
>   at the same time), then you will need to ensure there is something
>   that is different about them to associate them with different
>   PendingIntents. This may be any of the Intent attributes considered by
>   Intent.filterEquals, or different request code integers supplied to
>   getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getActivities(Context, int,
>   Intent[], int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), or
>   getService(Context, int, Intent, int).
>
> If you only need one PendingIntent active at a time for any of the
>   Intents you will use, then you can alternatively use the flags
>   FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT to either cancel or modify
>   whatever current PendingIntent is associated with the Intent you are
>   supplying.